# Concat rows in symfony/doctrine/mysql without group_concat

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine, mariadb

I am new to symfony/doctrine and i am trying to build a querybuilder to see the answers of a multiple choice quizz.
In the databse each answer of the quizz is in a different row,so i would like to show all the answers of one question in one line.

During my search all solution suggested to create group_concat function in doctrine.But unfortunately i'm not allowed to do that :(

So is there any other way i can do the following without group_concat?

```
 ====================================
    TABLE NAME : answer

    id       anwser    
    ----------------------------
    1           a       
    1           d       
    1           e       
    2           a       
    2           c       
    2           f       
    3           a       
    3           b      
    3           c
```

to

```
====================================
TABLE NAME : tab

id          anwser    
----------------------------
1           a,d,e      
2           a,c,f       
3           a,b,c       




$serieQuestions = $this->createQueryBuilder('answer')
                ->select('tab')
                ->groupBy('tab.id')
                ->...
```

PS:This is just an example,the real query/database is way bigger

Answer (score 0):

`group_concat` is the only function that rolls up row results into a single column. What you have asked isn't possible in SQL.

You could get your application to look at the rows and when the question `id` is the same keep the output on the same line.